# How to get execution time of IDC script?

Tags: ida, script

As a beginner I'm trying to disassemble a file with IDA Pro 6.8. I write some IDC script for time-consuming work.

Now, I want to get the execution time of my script, but I can not find appropriate IDC function. Are there anyone to tell me how to write script get execution time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you would allow me to make a suggestion, I would highly recommend using idapython instead of idc. From what I've heard it seems easier to use/gives you all the python runtime too.

Comment: @Abigail: there may be reasons for using IDC over Python; we should try to answer the question as asked, unless it's obviously misguided.

Comment: Fair enough. @user6903 you could try using call_system in IDC to get the system time somehow and wrap your functionality within calls to get the system time.

Comment: @Abigail. I can not find call_system in the list of IDC functions for IDA Pro 6.8. You mean other version of the IDA Pro?

Comment: It's possibly called `Exec` in 6.8. I don't know - since I don't have IDA Pro. 

Since you're a customer I would try their support if nobody else here can help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you could do as a workaround for the missing time-support in Ida:

IDC has an "Exec" command (as mentioned in a comment) allowing you to make arbitrary calls to the OS. This might help. In the "Exec" bracktes you enter a command in much the same way as typing it on the command line.

The following is an idc script file

- Writing the date and time with some comment into the file
  C:\tmp\mytime.tim.
- Reading this file and displying its contents to    Ida's output
  window.

  ```
  static main()
  {
      writeTime();
  }

  static writeTime()
  {
      Exec ("echo Date of script run #1234 was %date% >> c:\\tmp\\mytime.tim");
      Exec ("echo Time of script run #1234 %time% >> c:\\tmp\\mytime.tim");
      print("Time written into C:\\tmp\\mytime.tim");

      auto h = fopen("c:\\tmp\\mytime.tim", "r");
      auto date = readstr(h);
      auto time = readstr(h);
      if (date != -1 && time != -1)
      {   
          Message("%s", date);
          Message("%s", time);
      }
      else
          Message("error\n");
      fclose(h);
  }
  ```

  Ida's output window shows the following:

[image]